# Objective - C Multiple interface iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, interface, controller

How can I do the following things in Objective C for interface for same class:

```
@interface DashControl : UIViewController <WitDelegate>
    @property(nonatomic, strong) id <WitDelegate> delegate; @end

@interface DashControl : DashWidget <ICustomizableIcon, ICustomizableActionText> @end
```

I would like to have one interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have exactly one class per identifier. (Even they are in different bundles.)

However, you want to do two different things. One is possible, the other one not:

A. A class can implement more than one protocol. Therefore it is possible to have something like that:

```
@interface DashControl : UIViewController <WitDelegate, ICustomizableIcon, ICustomizableActionText>
…
@end
```

(BTW: Deriving directly from UIViewController is a kind of special.)

B. A cannot inherit from more than base one base class. So it is impossible to derive from `UIViewController` and `DashWidget`.

However, you can publish the API of a second class as protocol, compose an instance of the second class into your class and use forward invocations. Then the instances of the original class can act as a second (or third) class. Let me know, if this is a solution for you.

Comment: I thought it was possible, i think to take your first solution and change inheritance.

Comment: Okay, but the second approach only has a couple of lines. Because of the dynamic dispatching you can forward messages without knowing anything about the back-end API. (So you do not have to maintain the front-end class for every change on the back-end.)